# Text Cleanup - Remove names in description from the given list of names

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have list of full names which can contain more than 10K names

```py
["name surname1", "name surname12"...., "name surname10000"]
```

I want to process a description and remove any of above names from it, names should be removed only when exact match is found. Description can have more than 1 name from the given list.

One approach I can think of

```py
description = """
Jakobe Lamb Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Edwin Day consectetuer adipiscing elit. Jakobe Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
"""
name_list = ["Jakobe Lamb", "Edwin Day", "Josue Houston"] # this will have more than 10K names
names_regex = r"|".join(names_list)
cleaned_description =  re.sub(names_regex,'', description)
```

but since the regex will become very large, will it be efficient? what can be the most efficient solution to achieve this?

Comment: The regex should work fine, though you should perhaps add word boundaries, like `r'\b(?:Jakobe Lamb|Edwin Day|Josue Houston)\b'`, to avoid having a name which is a substring of another name cause a false positive.

Comment: thanks, added word boundaries.